# How to create sea waves in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was making ocean waves in three.js but when I run it on web browser, it just displays white screen.

[image: WhietScreen]

The code I used to create the ocean waves is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/js/objects/Water.js"></script>   
        <script>


            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
            camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );
            

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            
            const WaterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 45, 45 );
            const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.imgur.com/mK9cHLq.jpeg' );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );           
            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            const params = {
                color: '#ffffff',
                scale: 4,
                flowX: 1,
                flowY: 1
            };


                water = new THREE.Water( WaterGeometry, material, {
                    color: params.color,
                    scale: params.scale,
                    flowDirection: new THREE.Vector2( params.flowX, params.flowY ),
                    textureWidth: 1024,
                    textureHeight: 1024
                } );



            controls.update();

            scene.add( water );

            function animate() 
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                water.rotation.x += 0.00;
                water.rotation.y += 0.00;
                water.rotation.z += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where did I messed up? All I now see is the slowly rotating black square now.

I thank you for all the feedbacks. How to fix this error?

Thank you!

[image: Black square]

Comment: *"import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"* - this has nothing to do with "sea waves"

Comment: @Rabbid76 I forgot to run the HTML code via XAMPP....I edited the HTML code in light of my mistake...

Answer (score 2):

Your imports are messed up. Try it like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/examples/js/objects/Water.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind to never import `three.js` files from different sources and releases.

Comment: I edited the HTML code in light of your suggestion. Only one error remained. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You have to access the `Water` class over the `THREE` namespace now. So: `water = new THREE.Water( WaterGeometry, {`

Comment: I have edited the HTML code in light of your suggestion. Did i wrote the code correct?

Comment: Why are you creating two times a `water` mesh? This code can't work since you assign a value to a `const` variable after its creation.

Comment: Holy...you're right...I used the `water` twice.....I edited the HTML in light of your quick eyes. But it only now displays a rotating black square object and not ocean waves.